# In Scrabble if you use all your letters to make up a word, do you get an extra points?

Tags: scrabble

In Scrabble, if you are able to use all your letters to make a word, do you get
any extra points?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, assuming you have a full hand of seven tiles. From [the rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules):

> BINGO! If you play seven tiles on a turn, it's a Bingo. You score a premium of 50 points after totaling your score for the turn.

If you have fewer than 7 tiles at the end of the game, playing them all doesn't get you this bonus.

Comment: And that guys, is how to turn a game with tiles and letters into a game with balls and numbers.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/2218/6352